# PHP DOM: change doctype of existing DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, doctype, domdocument

When creating a DOMDocument with [`DOMImplementation::createDocument()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocument.php), you can specify a doctype as the third argument in the constructor.  This doctype then gets "tied" to the document and you can retrieve it later with `$document->doctype`.

However, this is a read-only attribute (unlike encoding and version!).

Is there any way to change the doctype property of an existing DOMDocument object?

The only workaround I can think of is to create a new DOMDocument with the new doctype, and import then copy across the contents from the old one.

Comment: I guess that’s the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also seems possible to call $document->loadXML() again even if the document is already populated.  It wipes the document and regenerates it, but it is a way of changing the doctype variable on an existing object, and the new doctype does have an HTML representation unlike in my other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that in PHP (and therefore, I guess, in libxml) you can add and remove DOMDocumentType objects to an existing document just like regular nodes using methods like `$document->insertBefore()` and `$document->removeChild()`, etc.

Seems to work OK - changing it changes the $document->doctype value and everything.  It's quite undocumented though, and contradicts the W3 DOM standard which says it shouldn't be possible (in DOM Level 2 at least).  But handy to know that you can do it in PHP.

One downside is that saveHTML() does not "see" the new doctype, even though saveXML() does.

Comment: Ack! This didn't get formatted in any sensible way. Not sure how to fix that.

With DOMImplementation::createDocumentType, right?

I was going to start a new question asking "where am I supposed to get this new DOMDocumentType object", because there is no public constructor for DOMDocumentType. Then I dug a little deeper into the PHP DOM documentation and found createDocumentType.

So I'm guessing the way to do this is:
    $impl = new DOMImplementation();
    $newDocType = $impl->createDocumentType("root-node-name",
        "publicID", "systemID");

Right?