# How to add DOCTYPE in export xml?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, doctype

I exported a xml file in PHP using:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();        
$xmldoc->formatOutput = true;
$xmldoc->encoding="Shift_JIS";

// create root nodes
$root = $xmldoc->createElement("TableData");
$xmldoc->appendChild( $root );
$xmldoc->save($filename);
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS"?>
<TableData> </TableData>
```

Now, i want to add row  `<!DOCTYPE TableDef SYSTEM "TableData.dtd">` like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS"?>
    <!DOCTYPE TableDef SYSTEM "TableData.dtd">
   <TableData> </TableData>
```

How to add `DOCTYPE` in an exported xml? Thanks.

Comment: Check [DOMImplementation::createDocumentType](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php)

Comment: http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2009/03/adding-a-doctype-declaration-to-a-domdocument-in-php.html

Answer (score 3):

See [PHP DOM: change doctype of existing DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090835/php-dom-change-doctype-of-existing-domdocument)

> When creating a DOMDocument with [DOMImplementation::createDocument()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocument.php),
>   you can specify a doctype as the third argument in the constructor.
>   This doctype then gets "tied" to the document and you can retrieve it
>   later with $document->doctype.