# importing external dtd in a xml file generated by php code

Tags: php, xml, external, dtd

I have this code that generates a xml file from data stored in a db. I'd like to make the xml, generated by this code, import an external dtd file

```
$connessione = mysql_connect("localhost", "privatedigitallibrary1", "") or die("problemi connessione");
mysql_select_db("my_privatedigitallibrary1", $connessione) or die("problemi database");                 
extract( $_GET );       
$query = " SELECT * FROM schede WHERE codiceScheda = '$codiceScheda' ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("problemi query");     
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  


$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');


$domtree->formatOutput = true;
$domtree->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("scheda");
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('autoreScheda', $row['autoreScheda']));
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('dataCompilazione', $row['dataScheda']));
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('tipoDocumento', $row['tipoDocumento']));
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('paroleChiave', $row['parolaChiave1'].", ".$row['parolaChiave2'].", ".$row['parolaChiave3']));

$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('autoreDocumento', $row['autore']));
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('titoloDocumento', $row['titolo']));
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('annoDocumento', $row['anno']));   
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('url', $row['url']));
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('commento', $row['commento']));



$domtree->save('schede/xml_cod'.$codiceScheda.'.xml');

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=xml_cod'.$codiceScheda.'.xml');
header("Content-type: application/xml");
readfile('schede/xml_cod'.$codiceScheda.'.xml');
```

Comment: What do you mean by importing an external DTD file? Which DTD file in specific? You want to have an inline DTD then? Normally you just reference the DTD in a doctype element: [How add DOCTYPE in export xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13339976/367456)

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, but that was exactly what i was looking for, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Please upvote the existing answer (and question) if it helped you (and your reputation allows you so).